# "Bind" values in array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

So, I have this array.

```js
['declare', 'var', 'foo' '=', '"hello', 'world!"']
```

As you can see, this array is this sentence structure split by spaces: `declare var foo = "hello world!"`

My question is, how can I 'bind' both the `"hello` and `world!"` together, ONLY when the first begins with an `"` and the last ends with `"`? End result must be the following:

```js
['declare', 'var', 'foo', '=', '"hello world!"']
```

To clarify, there could also be other things in between, and I want to include them into the final result as well.

```
['declare', 'var', 'foo', '=', '"hello', 'there,', 'human."']
```

Result must be:

```
['declare', 'var', 'foo', '=', '"hello there, human."']
```

Comment: Please post whatever you've tried so far to fix this problem.

Comment: Is the initial input a string or an array?

Comment: @nickzoum Can be either. It's actually an array, but a string is also good.

Comment: @QSmally I'm only asking because some users ask [XY problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So I assumed that the original input was a string and then you used `String#split` to get the array.

Comment: If you're interested in the performance of the various answers given (I included only those resulting in the desired output including the double quotes), see https://jsperf.com/glue-quoted-strings-in-array2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using `reduce()` and keeping track of the double quotes. See the comments in the code for what is happening.

```js
var test1 = ['declare', 'var', 'foo', '=', '"hello', 'world!"'];
var test2 = ['declare', 'var', 'foo', '=', '"hello', 'there,', 'human."'];

function glueQuotedStrings(arrayIn) {
  var inQuotes = false;
  var textBuffer = '';
  var result = arrayIn.reduce(function(i, v) {
    if (v.charAt(0) === '"') {
      // begin quoted string
      inQuotes = true;
      textBuffer += v; 
    } else if(v.substr(-1) === '"') {
      // end quoted string
      inQuotes = false;
      i.push(textBuffer + ' ' + v);
      textBuffer = '';
    } else if (inQuotes) {
      // inside quoted string
      textBuffer += ' ' + v;
    } else {
      // ordinary item
      i.push(v);
    }
    
    return i;
  }, []);
  
  return result;
}

console.log(glueQuotedStrings(test1));
console.log(glueQuotedStrings(test2));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regex can solve this issue.

```js
let array = ['declare', 'var', 'foo', '=', '"hello', 'there,', 'human."'];

let newArray = replaceAll(array.join(), ',', ' ');

let splitted = newArray.split(/ (?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)|"/).filter(function(item) { return item !== '' });

function replaceAll(string, term, replacement) {
  return string.replace(
    new RegExp(term.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, "\\$&"), "g"),
    replacement
  );
};

console.log(splitted);
```

Comment: Ah! That's somewhat what I need, but is there a possibility to add the two `"` around that last element?

Comment: @QSmally can you show me, what the string will be after the quotes add?

Comment: It will be as follows: `['declare', 'var', 'foo', '=', '"hello there human!"']`. So, the quotes are still in the last element.

Comment: OP doesn't have a string they needs to split though, they have an array of strings, of which a subset of those strings need to be merged into a single array element string.

Comment: @QSmally use this regex `/ (?=(?:[^""]*""[^"]*"")*[^""]*$)|""/` will solve your double quotes problem

Comment: Updated the answer have a look. Thanks, @ThomasPreston for finding the issue.

Comment: @Yahiya Using the second regex you provided, that was going to fix the quoting problem, makes the array not split it all. I'd like the last element, originally the elements with the quotes, to also have the quotes surrounding it. Could you help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = ['declare', 'var', 'foo', '=', '"hello', 'there,', 'human."'];
let resultArr = [];
let concatString = '';
for (let el of arr) {
  if (el.startsWith('"')) {
    concatString += el + ' ';
  }
  else if (concatString.length) {
    if (el.endsWith('"')) {
      concatString += el;
      resultArr.push(concatString);
      concatString = '';
    }
    else {
      concatString += el + ' ';
    }
  }
  else {
    resultArr.push(el);
  }
}

console.log(resultArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to tackle this problem is to keep track of the quotes and do the `String#split` part yourself.

```js
var text = 'declare var foo = "hello world!"';
var quotes = undefined;
var result = [].reduce.call(text, function(result, char) {
  if (/\s/.test(char) && !quotes) return result.push(""), result; // start new string and skip iteration
  if (quotes === char) quotes = undefined; // exit quotes
  else if (!quotes && /'|"|`/.test(char)) quotes = char; // enter quotes
  result[result.length - 1] += char; // add character to string
  return result;
}, [""]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The OP has an array of strings to operate on, not a string.  The goal is to merge a subset of those string array elements into a single array element.